# Adding "widgets" live to a site

Tags: php, jquery, html, widget

I'm currently in the process of creating a website with various widgets that I want to be able to add/remove on the fly.

I'm using jQuery to achieve this(planning to at least).

The simplest widget is the login widget. Which looks like this:

```
<div id="widget1">
    <div class="close"></div>
    <div id="widget1_title"></div>
    <div id="widget1_content">


        <form method='post' action='index.php'>
        <div id="widget1_username">
        Username<input type='text' maxlength='16' name='user' value='' />
        </div>

        <div id="widget1_password">
        Password<input type='password' maxlength='16' name='pass' value='' />
        </div>

        <div id="widget1_submit">
        <input type='submit' value='LOGIN' />
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

This is stored in a file called login_widget.html. Since a login-widget is something that should be preloaded on the site(without the user having to bring it up) I have my index.php file looking like this:

```
<body>



    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="sidebar">
                <div id="login-sidebar"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="header">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div id="header-logo"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="main-content">

                <div id="widget1">
                    <div class="close"></div>
                    <div id="widget1_title"></div>
                    <div id="widget1_content">


                        <form method='post' action='index.php'>
                        <div id="widget1_username">
                        Username<input type='text' maxlength='16' name='user' value='' />
                        </div>

                        <div id="widget1_password">
                        Password<input type='password' maxlength='16' name='pass' value='' />
                        </div>

                        <div id="widget1_submit">
                        <input type='submit' value='LOGIN' />
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>              


            </div>

            <div id="footer">

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>


</body>
```

(Originally it's in a `<?php include_once('login_widget.html'); ?>` ).

I then have a button set up that I press to load in the code from the file.

Here's the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){



$(".close").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});


$("#login-sidebar").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'login_widget.html'
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#main-content').append(data);
    }); 
});

});
```

And now to the problem. This works in that it posts the html-code and it shows on the site, but the problem is that the "close button" doesn't work anymore. So I can't remove the new created html-elements using the class named "close".

I'm very new to jQuery, but I figure this is one way of doing it, but I'm missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you don't actually add the widgets until after the page has loaded? the `$(jQuery).click()` function won't work on dynamically added elements. Depending on your version of jQuery, you can use the `.live()` function ([.live() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/)) or the `.on()` function ([.on() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)).

Comment: @baacke it's safe to assume that he has at least the delegate method since he is using deferred objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either build your widgets as modules that bind their own events when they are created to remove themselves, or use event delegation. Event delegation would be the simplest given the very basic code that you are using thus far.

```
$("#main-content").on("click",".close",function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

Comment: Thank you, this code works perfectly. As I said, I'm just beginning jquery and such. It would be great if you could you point me in the direction of creating modules with events, since this sounds like something I would need in the future.

Comment: I would, but there's just so many different ways to do it, each one having pros and cons targeted at how/where it's being used. Basically, think of it as having a function that creates the widget when called. For example, `createLogin()`. that function would append the html for the widget and bind any events that the widget needs, such as the close event.